# What is the max value you can set ERRORS to for Oracle SQL*loader?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-loader

Straight forward question ..

The documentation for Oracle 10 states:

[Oracle 10g sql*loader documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm)

(Note, I linked to 10g since it was most convenient, I'll take an answer for Oracle 10 and/or Oracle 11, either way is fine - I suspect it'll be the same answer though - so I added both tags).

> ERRORS (errors to allow)
>   Default: To see the default value for this parameter, invoke SQL*Loader without any parameters, as described in Invoking SQL*Loader.
>
> ERRORS specifies the maximum number of insert errors to allow. If the number of errors exceeds the value specified for ERRORS, then SQL*Loader terminates the load. To permit no errors at all, set ERRORS=0. To specify that all errors be allowed, **use a very high number.**

(Emphasis mine).

So, since Oracle handles up to NUMBER(38) .. I tried:

```
ERRORS=999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

(36 digits)

and promptly got this error:

> SQL*Loader-100: Syntax error on command-line

Trying a much smaller number:

```
ERRORS=999999
```

works fine.

So what's the maximum value you can use here ?
I don't find it in the documentation, so not sure if I'm looking in the wrong place, or it's just not in there :)

And yeah, I need a LARGE number, I'm loading a multi-million row file, so I'd like to use the largest possible to avoid any future issues.

Comment: So what version of Oracle did you try it on?

Comment: @Gary_W: as indicated in my question: both 10g and 11 ... same results in both so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO sqlldr is not supporting number(39). I think all number parameter in sql loader are integer data type. And common limits for integer is 2147483647.

```
sqlldr xxxx control=ctl.ctl errors=2147483648 -> exception 

sqlldr xxxx control=ctl.ctl errors=2147483647 -> works fine
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3. Not db version.

Comment: Arkadiusz: That makes sense now that you mention it :)  I'll likely accept this answer as correct, but I'll give time .. "just in case" :) Thanks!

Comment: @BobC: Read the documentation:  "To permit no errors at all, set ERRORS=0. To specify that all errors be allowed, use a very high number." I want to allow all errors - I'm going to check/verify later. ERRORS=0 means "Stop loading and Abend when you hit the first error". I want it to attempt to load as much as it can ... so I can get as many error records/reasons for reporting as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem setting

```
errors=-1
```

worked fine on Oracle 11g